# Angular Scripts are not loading when served using Express server

Tags: angular, typescript, express

My Application is running on express server.

After angular client is build, I'm using express to server to render my website.

My app is initiated only in this path,

```
https://example.com/login/myapp-samplepages
```

Issue is while, serving my application I'm getting this error,

```
Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'main-es2015.js'
```

This doesn't work `http://localhost.com:3000/login/runtime-es2015.js`

But this works `http://localhost.com:3000/runtime-es2015.js`

How can load this scripts, in this routes `\login`

*****UPDATE*****

With the below code it's fine

```
junctionRouter.use(`/0-es5.js`, express.static(path.join('dist/client/0-es5.js')));
junctionRouter.use(`/0-es2015.js`, express.static(path.join('dist/client/0-es2015.js')));
junctionRouter.use(`/1-es5.js`, express.static(path.join('dist/client/1-es5.js')));
junctionRouter.use(`/1-es2015.js`, express.static(path.join('dist/client/1-es2015.js')));
junctionRouter.use(`/2-es5.js`, express.static(path.join('dist/client/2-es5.js')));
junctionRouter.use(`/2-es2015.js`, express.static(path.join('dist/client/2-es2015.js')));
junctionRouter.use(`/3-es5.js`, express.static(path.join('dist/client/3-es5.js')));
junctionRouter.use(`/3-es2015.js`, express.static(path.join('dist/client/3-es2015.js')));
junctionRouter.use(`/4-es5.js`, express.static(path.join('dist/client/4-es5.js')));
junctionRouter.use(`/4-es2015.js`, express.static(path.join('dist/client/4-es2015.js')));
junctionRouter.use(`/5-es5.js`, express.static(path.join('dist/client/5-es5.js')));
junctionRouter.use(`/5-es2015.js`, express.static(path.join('dist/client/5-es2015.js')));
junctionRouter.use(`/main-es5.js`, express.static(path.join('dist/client/main-es5.js')));
junctionRouter.use(`/main-es2015.js`, express.static(path.join('dist/client/main-es2015.js')));
junctionRouter.use(`/polyfills-es5.js`, express.static(path.join('dist/client/polyfills-es5.js')));
junctionRouter.use(`/polyfills-es2015.js`, express.static(path.join('dist/client/polyfills-es2015.js')));
junctionRouter.use(`/runtime-es5.js`, express.static(path.join('dist/client/runtime-es5.js')));
junctionRouter.use(`/runtime-es2015.js`, express.static(path.join('dist/client/runtime-es2015.js')));
```

But is there any better way of doing it ?

Comment: check for `express.static()`

Comment: Why you are not serving index.html from dist folder? That would solve your issue.